# Error installing cumulative update pack "2022-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5016623)" on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, windows-update

Good morning!

I am trying to install the update package "2022-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5016623)" on Windows Server 2019 (Running on vSphere and using English version - No language Packs installed). But when restarts windows says "We could complete the updates - undoing changes".

Windows Events says: "Erro on update: 0x80246007 - Some update didn't finnish downloading. We'll keep trying"

I already tried to download install the package manually. But runs the same error.

Actions I've tried:

1. Cleaned up the windows and disks to get more space;
2. Executed the Trobleshooting;
3. Started BITS;
4. Restarted all services related to Windows Update;
5. Run: DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth;
6. Run: SFC /SCANNOW
7. Cleaned the Temporary folders of Windows, Windows Update, folder "SoftwareDistribution", "WinSxS";
8. Removed "migration.xml" and "pending.xml" from "WinSxS" folder;
9. Cleaned the CBS Logs;
10. I removed all apps and then tried to install again;
11. I removed all updates and then tried to install again;

...but the problem persists! Any suggestions for solutions? Anyone else going through this?

Update 10/18/2022: The problema persist, but now installing the following packages:

- KB5018419 (OS Build 17763.3532)
- KB5017315 (OS Build 17763.3406)

Comment: sometimes it helps to wait some days...

Comment: I'd say there's not enough information to go with just yet. The CBS log file should have some extra insight into the actual cause of the error. Have you checked this log after clearing it (and re-running the update)? PS. AFAIK clearing the CBS log is unlikely to ever actually fix any problem since it's just a log. ;) But if it gets too big it becomes hard to look for issues.